# data frame into matrix in R

Tags: r, csv

I need to import data from csv file and later do computations with it as with usual matrix in R. Data in csv file contain only numbers except variable names in header. I used following commands:

```
XX <- read.table("C:/Users/.../myfile.csv", header = TRUE)
```

and got something resembling a matrix, with numbers separated with comas. Then:

```
X<- as.matrix(sapply(XX, as.numeric))
```

which gave me just column vector with strange numbers. What am i doing wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: If it's a real csv file, then use `read.csv` or add `sep = ","` to your `read.table` call.  Showing a few lines of `XX` would help diagnose this.

Comment: what does the class(XX) return? what do your original data look like?

Comment: Thanks for comments, read.csv solved the problem :)